# Connecting to BLE beacons without pairing

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

We have a couple of beacons that needs to "light" up when in the presence of an android device with bluetooth activated and present in our app. Like a physical "path way". But since we have many individual, we cant ask the user to pair with every single one.

We have no experience with this at all, how do we proceed with this? As far as I can see in my googling its entirely possible, we just have no idea how to proceed with it.

We have BLE connected to an arduino and ready to transmit data. http://www.aliexpress.com/store/product/Bluetooth-4-0-single-chip-module-package-BLE-transparent-wireless-serial-100-meters-iphone-Andrews-are/1110497_1656480722.html

Any help or if anyone knows any guides to connect without pairing would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: No one knows anything about this? :(

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately BLE beacons are only designed to transmit simple advertisement data. I don't think you'll be able to do what you want with this hardware without pairing. That being said... The phone will know how close it is to the beacon so if you can think of a way for the phone to talk to a central hub that controls the lights that may be a possible solution?

Comment: It's not possible for the app to send back something to the BLE making arduino flare up the LED ? Without it pairing? Through insecureRFcommsocket something?